# Pipe a struct from multiple children in C

Tags: c, struct, operating-system, pipe

### Background:

I am doing a school assignment with the task of subsampling an image and using processes to simulate "servers" doing the calculations of certain pixels in the image. I'm very close to getting the assignment to work but I'm having a weird bug with reading and writing a struct with a pipe from multiple children to the parent.

To illustrate this I tried to do a much simpler example without all the image subsampling stuff. I found that I was not able to get this very simple code to print the numbers 1-50 so maybe there is a bug in this code that I'm just not realizing or understanding properly.

---

### Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// Create a struct to hold the index
struct Thing {
    int index;
};

int main() {

    pid_t pid;
    int processLabel;
    int c2p[2];
    int p = 2;

    // create p number child processes
    for(processLabel = 0; processLabel < p; processLabel++)
    {
        if(pipe(c2p) == -1)
        {
            perror( "pipe Failed" );
            continue;
        }

        pid = fork();

        if(pid  == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (pid == 0) { // child process
        int count = 0;

        // close read from parent process
        close(c2p[0]);

        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            // write the index to parent depending on what child process we are in
            if(count % p == processLabel){
                struct Thing test;
                test.index = count;
                write(c2p[1], &test, sizeof(test));
            }
            count++;
        }
        close(c2p[1]);
    }
    else { // parent
        close(c2p[1]);
        
        // read structs from child processes
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            struct Thing test;
            read(c2p[0], &test, sizeof(test));
            printf("index: %d\n", test.index);
        }

        close(c2p[0]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The purpose of `if(count % p == processLabel)` is in my actual code for the assignment the child processes each do calculations on certain parts of the image. It is to "simulate" a server doing calculations of different parts of image to speed up the image subsampling.

---

### Output:

The output that I receive from this code when `p` is 2 is the following:

```
index: 1
index: 3
index: 5
index: 7
index: 9
index: 11
index: 13
index: 15
index: 17
index: 19
index: 21
index: 23
index: 25
index: 27
index: 29
index: 31
index: 33
index: 35
index: 37
index: 39
index: 41
index: 43
index: 45
index: 47
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
index: 49
```

As you can see it only prints out the odd numbers in the parent when I want it to print out 0 to 49. The interesting thing is when I change our value of `p` number of processes to 1, the code works properly and counts from 0-49.

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Tip: `i` and `count` have exactly the same value at all times, so there's no point to having two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two pipes, but only reading from one.

Simple solution: Move the call to `pipe` outside of the loop.

I believe the writes are guaranteed to be atomic if they're under a certain size, so this is safe as long as the structure is small enough.

Comment: Thanks so much. My assignment now works! Literally all I had to do was move the pipe outside the for loop and then I got the exact results I was looking for. I appreciate you taking the time to look over my code and help me!